# JavaScript dot notation

Tags: javascript, syntax

The following line is apparently written best in dot notation. I am trying to clean my JavaScript code to make it strict. What does it mean?

```
if (ie||ns6)
{
    var tipobj=document.all? document.all["dhtmltooltip"] : document.getElementById? document.getElementById("dhtmltooltip") : "";
}
```

I added some context to my line of code, in case this helps?
I know nothing about [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). I am not trying to support Internet Explorer 4, this is not my code and I wouldn't be able to write JavaScript myself. I am only trying to get it compliant and the [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) tool says about this line:

> Problem at line 17 character 43: ['dhtmltooltip'] is better written in dot notation.

Comment: You should test for .getElementById first, because some browsers fake .all for backwards compatibility; and byId is the functionality you're really looking for.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, there doesn't seem to be any performance benefit of using either notation: http://jsperf.com/dot-notation-vs-square-bracket-notation

Comment: If you look for a reason to use a.b instead of a['b'] check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24858166/1090562)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There are [two ways to access properties of an object in JavaScript](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/).

**Dot notation**

```
foo.bar.baz
```

**Square bracket notation**

```
foo['bar']['baz']
```

You are using the latter in part of your code.

Douglas Crockford, who wrote JSLint (a tool which gives that error message), is of the opinion that is is better to use dot notation where possible.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it! You seem to consider his opinion not necessarily 100% valid tho, is there a better way then JSLint to validate my code?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way to validate the JS code, other than running it and testing it.  I think the point @David Dorward was trying to make is that both are valid, and it is just a matter of style.  The dot notation is the more preferred style, by most people, but there is nothing inherently wrong with using the square bracket notation.

Comment: Thanks pkaeding. What lead me to using JSLint in the first place was the w3 validator that said :<br/>

 character "&amp;" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data <br/>

so I figured I'd check that entire script, but this particular error didn't even come up..I'll make it another question if I don't find a way!

Comment: DN is slightly more efficient than SBN, and is usually more readable. There are situations where I think that SBN is more readable, but that probably has more to do with the conventions I am used to than anything else. JSLint is a decent tool, don't take the wording of my answer as a criticism of it, my aim was to avoid promoting or disparaging it.

Comment: A markup validator will pick up issues related to expressing JavaScript in an HTML document. JSLint will not, it looks only at the JS, not the representation of it in a document.

Comment: There is a third reason for using SBN in addition to the two reasons given in the reference sited. If one wants write code that can be minified with the Closure Compiler's ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS option, then any globally reference symbols have to be exported. See [Export Symbols You Want to Keep](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3). The string literal used in SBN won't be replaced by the compiler.

Comment: Here’s a slightly more in-depth blog post, for those interested in the spec details: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties

Comment: I agree with this lintage 99% of the time.. But when you have something like: obj[var1]['foo'][var2], I prefer to use brackets all the way through for readability rather than obj[var1].foo['var2] which I find more difficult to scan.

Answer (score 16):

JSLint wants this:

```
var tipobj= document.all ? document.all.dhtmltooltip
                         : document.getElementById 
                           ? document.getElementById("dhtmltooltip") 
                           : "";
```

But nowadays is completely safe to assume that `document.getElementById` exists, it was introduced on the [DOM Level Core 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) as of year 2000.

`document.all` is dead, unless you try to support really old browsers like IE4 (12 year old!):

```
var tipobj = document.getElementById("dhtmltooltip");
```

The two above snippets are a good example about the *complexity cost* of supporting very [old browser](http://ejohn.org/blog/determining-browser-market-share/) versions:

[image]

Comment: Does this line replace mine entirely?

Comment: Yes, unless you want to support IE 4 or older.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to be more user-friendly.

```
var tipobj;
if (document.all)
    tipobj = document.all["dhtmltooltip"];
else if (document.getElementById)
    tipobj = document.getElementById("dhtmltooltip");
else
    tipobj = "";
```

Comment: Perhaps, but it still uses square bracket notation, so doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You can change `document.all["dhtmltooltip"]` to `document.all.dhtmltooltip` if you like.

Comment: You can, and that is the core of what the question is about.

Comment: This answer should be a comment...it doesn't even attempt to answer the actual question, just gives some formatting advice on the side.

Answer (score 0):

It's using capability checking to retrieve an element with the id `dhtmltooltip` and falling back to an empty `String` if there is not a capability for doing the retrieval.

**UPDATE**: As others have pointed out, the check for `getElementById` should be first, and could probably be omitted since any browser that could be called "modern" with a straight face has had it for a long time.

**UPDATE 2**: With the new context, JSLint is complaining that it isn't `document.all.dhtmltooltip`. You should probably just rewrite the whole thing as:

```
var tipobj = document.getElementById("dhtmltooltip");
```

and be done with it.

Comment: What does that have to do with using dot notation?

Comment: So this line would replace my entire line, make it lighter and more current but still work the same?

Comment: As long as you don't care about supporting IE 4 and other incredibly ancient browsers.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search says that `document.all` is only used to support IE4. It is an array that allows the browser to access different parts of the DOM (see [here](http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/worst_4.htm).)

The code you posted first checks if document.all exists. If not, it sets `tipobj` to `""`. Now, beyond this, it's not really worth deciphering the line you posted unless you *really* want IE4 support. Since very few people still use IE4 and this piece of code isn't compliant to any modern standards, I'd just drop that line and set `tipobj` to `""`.

Comment: What does that have to do with using dot notation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only real issues are formatting/syntax. This should work exactly the same and conform to javascript best practice.  The main difference is using javascript dot notation instead of bracket notation.

```
if (ie || ns6) {
    var tipobj = document.all ? document.all.dhtmltooltip : document.getElementById ? document.getElementById("dhtmltooltip") : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just use:

```
var tipobj = dhtmltooltip.id
```

Not sure why the long version is required unless the dot notation doesnt work in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

If the dot notation is a problem, you can always set the /*jslint sub: true */ option to override it.

Answer (score 0):

As is was answered by Quentin [both ways are valid](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/).

One of the reasons why I prefer to use `elem.bar` instead of `elem['bar']` is that it saves 3 characters. Surely this is not a big improvement, but a free 3 bites per assignment is not bad.