# JS output from data structure to table

Tags: javascript, html-table

Data Structure

```
var X = {
   a: [{name:"john", phone:777},{name:"john", phone:777},{name:"john", phone:777}],
   b: [{name:"john", phone:777},{name:"john", phone:777},{name:"john", phone:777}],
   c: [{name:"john", phone:777},{name:"john", phone:777},{name:"john", phone:777}],
   d: [{name:"john", phone:777},{name:"john", phone:777},{name:"john", phone:777}]
}
```

Function

```
function showTable(trnum,X,a) {
    var Tablecode = "<table><tbody>";
    for (var i=0; i< X.a.length;i++) {
        for (var j=0; j< trnum; j++) {
            Tablecode += "<tr><td>"+X.a[i].name+"</td><td>"+X.a[i].phone+"</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    Tablecode += "</tbody></table>";
    $("#elem").append(Tablecode);
}
```

Markup

```
<body>
    <button onclick="showTable(4,X,"a");"></button>
    <div id="elem">
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to output data to table according to letter. one object on one table row.(all objects in table within one letter). this code doesn't work- unexpected token `"}"`. oddly enough, it points to `<div id="elem">` line. but there's no such character! How can I fix this?

UPDATE: thanks, error disappeared... but it outputs the whole structure, how do I make it output only 'a' objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button onclick="showTable(4,X,"a");"></button>
```

should be like that (doublequotes):

```
<button onclick="showTable(4,X,'a');"></button>
```

Compare this one to yours (see `.a` and `[a]`)

```
for (var i=0; i< X[a].length;i++){
 for (var j=0; j< trnum; j++){
 Tablecode += "<tr><td>"+X[a][i].name+"</td><td>"+X[a][i].phone+"</td></tr>";
 }

}
```

[Feature reading about javascript notations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001360/javascript-dot-notation/2001410#2001410)

Comment: thanks, error disappeared... but it outputs the whole structure, how do i make it output only 'a' objects??

Comment: 12 beacuse `X[a]length(=3) * trnum (=4) = 12` You have 2 loops

Comment: i see.. is there a chance to fix this?? to get only 3 (under 'a')johns??

Comment: yes, remove `for (var j=0; j< trnum; j++){` and `}` after `Tablecode += ...` . When you done this you can also change: 
 `showTable(4,X,'a');` to `showTable(X,'a');` and `function showTable(trnum,X,a) {
` for `function showTable(X,a) {`

Comment: thanks a lot!! you nailed it!! :) sorry but i have last question: how to disable button after first click?? to make it clickable but unexecutable after first click??

Comment: The shortest but, not so style-good result, is to add at the beggining of showTable function this line of code: `if ( window.mem__ ) { return;} window.mem__ = 1;`

Comment: Thanks!! Definitely THE BEST ANSWER!! :)

Answer (score 0):

From tossing your code into a fiddle and getting it to run, I noticed that your button is a failure point. You have to surround the 'a' with SINGLE quotes.

http://jsfiddle.net/YaZp2/1/

EDIT: Also, edited the output code added the ability to actually see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes used to delimit the onclick and also the params within.

Try

```
<button onclick="showTable(4,X,'a');">
```