# How to suppress "{variable} is better written in dot notation."

Tags: javascript, syntax, properties, jshint

Is there an option to and/or how do I suppress errors like the following?

> 175,14:['tracker'] is better written in dot notation.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If it's a feature and not a bug, place this at the top of your file.

```
/*jshint sub:true*/
```

If it's a bug, you should refactor your code

```
foo['tracker'] = bar // from this...
foo.tracker = bar;   // to this!
```

Good post on the reasons here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2001410/94668

As suggested by: [@ThorSummoner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695680/thorsummoner) you can use below in your .jshintrc file

```
"sub": true
```

Comment: This always bugged me cause the only way to reference elements in an associative array whose keys are reserved keywords is to use the bracket style. It'd be nice if jsHint could check the value in the brackets and not generate the warning if it's a JS keyword. Otherwise, jsLint ends up telling me to write something in dot notation that would cause a syntax error :P

Comment: @reblace JSHint (note, *not the same as jsLint*) [supposedly does exactly that](http://jslinterrors.com/a-is-better-written-in-dot-notation).

Comment: that's `"sub": true,` in your .jshintrc file

Comment: I hoped for the linked "good post" to give me a reason, why I should prefer the dot notation over the bracket notation. The only reason the post gives, is that JSLint's author decided so. 
To me it's still just a matter of preference and not correctness, so why are JSLint/JSHint marking it as warning?

Comment: @whY I prefer dot notation as you can hover over the property while debugging to see the value while with bracket notation debugger cant evaluate it on hover.

Comment: It doesn't work when adding a new key to JSON object. Like, `let obj = {"name":"okay", "address":"India"};` // now adding a new property to this object, won't work.
`obj.gender = "M";` // while it works ...`obj["gender"] = "M"`

Answer (score 16):

In JSHint 1.0.0 and above you have the ability to ignore any warning with a [special option syntax](http://jshint.com/docs/#options). The identifier of this warning is *W069*.

This means you can tell JSHint to not issue this warning with the `/*jshint -W069 */` directive.

You can even wrap several lines of code and then reenable the warning as the example below (with a note to future you why it was a good idea):

```
/*jshint -W069 */
/*Disable Warning Justification:
    Using bracket notation so Google Closure Compiler 
    ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS will keep the original property names. */
obj['prop1'] ='foo';
obj['prop2'] ='bar';
/*jshint +W069 */
```

Comment: You can also ignore it with `/*jshint sub:true*/` per the answer

Comment: Enabling/disabling a single piece of code while lint'ing the rest of the file is a great way to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking about Dreamweaver or another editor.

**Dreamweaver**

You may go to **Edit** -> **Preferences** -> **Linting**

Select **JS** in the dropdown and hit **Edit & Apply changes**

Find

```
 "sub": false,
```

and change that to **true**.  Save the file and that notice will disappear.

If you have OTHER Linting things you wish to edit, you can find a helpful list of them all at https://jshint.com/docs/options/

Comment: It should be the opposite to disable this warning.
 ```"sub": true,```