# difference between dot notation and bracket notation in javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax, brackets

I am trying to understand the difference between `.Notation` and `[]` notation. In my problem below when I use `if (object[key] === true)` I get the correct answer. When I use `if (object.key === true)` it does not work. Could someone explain why it's different.

```
var myObj = {
    one: false,
    two: false,
    three: false,
    four: true,
    five: false,
    six: false
};
var myFunc = function (object) {
    for (var key in object) {
        if (object[key] === true) {
            return "There is a true value in this object";
        } else {

        }
    }
    return "Sorry, there are no true values in this object";
};
```

Comment: Never name your variables as `object`

Comment: In dot notation you access keys by name, in bracket notation by string. The later can be dynamic.

Comment: @thefourtheye, why specifically should a variable not be named object? Thanks.

Comment: @jstone There is a built-in JavaScript object named [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), so its better not to name the variables with the same name even if the case is different.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you use dot notation, `key` means the actual property in the object, which will not be there. So, `undefined` is returned which is not equal to `true`.

When you use `[]` notation you are accessing the property in the object with the name in the variable `key`. So, that will work.

For example,

```
var myObj = {
    myVar : 1
};

for (var key in myObj) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(myObj.key);
    console.log(myObj[key]);
}
```

This will print,

```
myVar
undefined
1
```

Because, `myObj` has no member named `key` (`myObj.key` tries to get the member with the name `key`) and in the next case, `myObj` has a member named `myVar` (`myObj[key]` tries to get the member with the value in `key`).

**Dot Notation**

[jslint prefers dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13271195/1903116).

**[] Notation**

This offers flexibility. You can dynamically access the members with a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Dot notation is faster to write and clearer to read.

Square bracket notation allows access to properties containing special characters and selection of properties using variables.

```
<form id="myForm">
<div><label>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="1"> 1
</label></div>
<div><label>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="2"> 2
</label></div>
<div><label>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="3"> 3
</label></div>
</form>
```

Example with errors:

```
var inputs = myForm.foo[];
```

Square bracket notation, on the other hand, allows:

```
var inputs = myForm["foo[]"];
```

Since the square brackets are part of a string, their special meaning doesn't apply.The second advantage of square bracket notation is when dealing with variable property names.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
doSomething(myForm["myControlNumber" + i]);
}
```