# Build a dynamic json tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I would like to make a JSON tree from an array.
My array is formed like that :

```
var arraySource = [];
arraySource.push({key : "fr", value: "france"});
arraySource.push({key : "es", value: "spain"});
//...

console.debug(arraySource);
```

I would like to make a json tree formed like that

```
var destJson = {
                 "fr" : "france",
                 "es" : "spain"
               };
```

I don't see how to make this dynamically because to make it I must do

```
destJson.fr = "france"
```

but it is not possible because items in the array are dynamics

Any idea ?
If you want to play I have made a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/lgm42/8L2Kf/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of dynamic keys in JavaScript there is a [**square bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
$.each(arraySource, function(index, item) {
    destJson[item.key] = item.value;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8L2Kf/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite complete. 
You just need to save values in json.

You can access array directly by

```
 destJson[item.key]
```

or

```
 destJson[item['key']]
```

and save value contained in:

```
item.value
```

or

```
item['value']
```

So you have:

```
destJson[item.key] = item.value;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8L2Kf/4/)** starting from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object and add the keys to it dynamically using bracket rather than dot notation:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  obj[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jgKLN/)

There's some [more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736758/difference-between-dot-notation-and-bracket-notation-in-javascript).