# javascript - dot vs bracket notation in enumeration

Tags: javascript, object, properties, notation

I do know there's some differences between dot and bracket notations but for this specific problem I am a bit confused why the dot notation wouldn't work and bracket does.

```
var rockSpearguns = {
  Sharpshooter: {barbs: 2, weight: 10, heft: "overhand"},
  Pokepistol: {barbs: 4, weight: 8, heft: "shoulder"},
  Javelinjet: {barbs: 4, weight: 12, heft: "waist"},
  Firefork: {barbs: 6, weight: 8, heft: "overhand"}
};

function listGuns (guns) {
    for(var speargun in guns){
        console.log("Behold! "+speargun+", with "+ guns[speargun].heft +" heft!");
    }
}
```

the part I am a bit confused is `guns[speargun].heft` this would work properly but if I do `guns.speargun.heft` then it will be undefined.

Since the properties in the rockSpearguns are all just one word shouldn't `gun.speargun` still able to call out the properties too?

I have thought a bit was the reason because now `speargun` is a string that if putting into `gun.speargun` it actually becomes something like `gun."speargun"` because if using bracket notation we just do `gun[speargun]` instead of using `gun["speargun"]` because this will just make it a double quote which is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between dot notation and bracket notation in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736758/difference-between-dot-notation-and-bracket-notation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because there is no speargun property in the rockSpearguns object.

> The reason is that in a JS object, all property keys are strings. When you use dot notation, JS is thinking you are looking for a key with the explicit key of whatever is after the dot.

In your code `var speargun` is being replaced with a string value of each of the properties inside the rockSpearguns object.

So, `guns[speargun].heft` translates to `guns["Sharpshooter"].heft`

I suggest you to read [this article](https://medium.com/@prufrock123/js-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-797c4e34f01d#.6jvog0bsh).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah is really ambiguous, there is a rules of thumb:

1. use brackets when the property value to access is generated dynamically, example:

   ```
   var Person = {
       name: 'John',
       lastName: 'Doe'
   };

   var propertyToCheck = 'name';

   console.log(Person.propertyToCheck); //error!
   console.log(Person[propertyToCheck]); //correct way
   ```
2. use dots when the property value to access is not generated dynamically(you know the property beforehand), example:

   ```
    var Person = {
        name: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    };

   console.log(Person.name);
   ```

By the way, you can use brackets in both cases, but I prefer to choose what I just mentioned above because using brackets seem you are working with arrays and not with objects

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of

```
speargun = 'Sharpshooter';
guns[speargun].heft
```

is

```
guns['Sharpshooter'].heft
```

or

```
guns.Sharpshooter.heft
```

because the variable in square brackets is evaluated and the content is inserted into the brackets. You get the second paragraph.

If you have a string literal, then you can use it as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for the object with dots.

In your above case, you use

```
guns.speargun.heft
```

which does not exist, because you have no property `speargun` in the object `guns`.