# Authorization is better written in dot notation

Tags: javascript, web, mern

I faced a problem in my mern app. how to fix it. thank

```html
src\utils\setAuthToken.js
  Line 5:35:  ["Authorization"] is better written in dot notation  dot-notation
  Line 7:42:  ["Authorization"] is better written in dot notation  dot-notation

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

my code:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const setAuthToken = (token) => {
  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  } else {
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
  }
};
export default setAuthToken;
```

Comment: specify it as axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization

Comment: yeah, thank you, i found the solution to the problem from Remi's link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001360/javascript-dot-notation/2001410#2001410

Comment: thankyou  [Gijs Beijer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2224937/gijs-beijer)